# Seperating input and put into dynamic array in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I work on Visual Studio about Python 3 Project.
I serate the integer input with this code:

```
dynamic_arrayList = [ ]
hexdec = input("Enter even number ");
strArray = [hexdec[idx:idx+2]  for idx in range(len(hexdec)) if idx%2 == 0]
dynamic_arrayList.append(strArray)
print(dynamic_arrayList)
```

After a while when the user enter `011001` the output is `[["01","10","01"]]`

When I call the first element on the list it gives the whole numbers of `["01","10","01"]` but I only want to see `01`
Is there any way to do it?

Comment: totally unrelated but python lists are "dynamic arrays" so naming your list "dynamic_arrayList" is a bit of a pleonasm. It's also a very poor name as it describes the type of the variable (which we all can tell from reading the code) instead of what the variable is used for, and more over mixes two naming conventions - "all_lower" and "mixedCase" - making your naming convention inconsistant (=> harder to remember, more chances of typos).

Comment: Thank you so much @brunodesthuilliers I will fix it too. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you are appending a `list` to another `list` by doing `dynamic_arrayList.append(strArray)`.

If you do not want list inside a list do something like this instead:

```
dynamic_arrayList = [ ]
hexdec = input("Enter even number ");
strArray = [hexdec[idx:idx+2]  for idx in range(len(hexdec)) if idx%2 == 0]
dynamic_arrayList += strArray
print(dynamic_arrayList)
```

or do this: `dynamic_arrayList = strArray`.

If you do not want to change the structure of `dynamic_arrayList` you can access the first element like this:  **`dynamic_arrayList[0][0]`**.

Comment: Thank you so much @BlackBeard your all solution makes it right. You safe my life, You are Awesome

Answer (score 0):

It's a nested list, so you can call the first element `[0]` and get the list inside the list, then call the first element of that:

First element of `[["01","10","01"]]` is `["01","10","01"]` and first element of `["01","10","01"]` is `01`.

```
dynamic_arrayList = [ ]
hexdec = input("Enter even number ");
strArray = [hexdec[idx:idx+2]  for idx in range(len(hexdec)) if idx%2 == 0]
dynamic_arrayList.append(strArray)
print(dynamic_arrayList[0][0])
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Piotrek your solution made it correct thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You're appending the list `strArray` to another list `dynamic_arrayList`, so the values of `strArray` becomes nested within a list of lists.

You can access the value `01` with `dynamic_arrayList[0][0]`, as in the first element in the first sub-list of the `dynamic_arrayList` list, or if there's no good reason to nest `strArray` within another list, you should simply access the item with `strArray[0]` instead.